Jenkins on Azure
Azure web app:
Java 17
Tomcat 10.0
I'm working on a team project for my studies, which involves creating a web application (focusing on the development process itself). I would like to set up Jenkins in such a way that each team member has access to it. The entire project is hosted on Azure, so it would be best to deploy Jenkins there. The problem is that the official documentation presents a method using a VM, which is not covered by the free subscription provided by the university. Also, as far as I know, Azure CLI is also paid. I've been thinking about deploying Jenkins as an Azure web app, but I have no idea how to do it.
I tried to upload the jenkins.war file (and the same file renamed to app.war) to the wwwroot folder, just like I did with our created application. However, after launching the web app, only a 404 page appears. I checked the logs, but I didn't find anything suspicious.
Next, I tried to manually launch the jenkins.war file (via webssh) using the command java -jar jenkins.war. Everything went successfully (output was the same as when running it locally), but I don't know how to access localhost.

Are container apps included in your free sub ?

@Himanshu Yes they are, but those have limited storage of 0,5 GB so it might not be enough.

You can directly install the Jenkins in your Azure ubuntu VM without a need to use Jenkins marketplace vm by running the commands below on your ubuntu vm's terminal or by referring to this Ms document.
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre -y
curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null
echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install jenkins -y
sudo service jenkins restart

Also, Azure cloud shell is available to use in Azure Free Trial as well, You can use the Bash from Azure portal cloud shell directly or install Azure CLI locally and then run azure commands.
To install Azure cli for windows and linux refer this MS Document1 and MS Document2
And then run az login with a**az account set --subscription "Subscription-name"** commands in your local terminal.
I tried installing jenkins.war file in Azure Web app with JAVA runtime but it failed. Refer below:-
Command to deploy war file:-
az webapp deploy --resource-group v-sidesai-mindtree --name siliconjenkins --src-path ./<package-name>.war

And add the startup command as below:-
java -jar -Dserver.port=8080 app.war


As I said, "The problem is that the official documentation presents a method using a VM, which is not covered by the free subscription provided by the university.".
However, if there is an option to obtain a free Azure Ubuntu VM, please explain how to create it. The official documentation only shows how to create a VM that is not covered by my academic subscription. Thank you.
